# How get passport var on routes with express load

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to use passport local strategy in my app but the passport variable is undefined on the index.js route. Below is my codes from app.js, passport.js and my index.js route.

Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var load = require("express-load");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var expressSession = require("express-session");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var passport = require('passport');
var error = require('./middlewares/error');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cookieParser('talkieparty'));
app.use(expressSession({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "149194"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

load('models').then('controllers').then('routes').into(app, passport);

app.use(error.notFound);
app.use(error.serverError);

var User = app.models.user;
var moment = require('moment');
process.on('message', function(data) {//Executa um função ordenada pelo master.
    console.log(process.pid + " executar: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    var action = data.action;
    switch(action) {
        case "confirmation-email-sended":
            var email = data.data.email;
            User.findOne({email: email}, function(error, user) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }else {
                    if(!user) {
                        return console.log("No user was found with e-mail like " + email);
                    }
                    user.register.notified = true;
                    user.register.notified_date = new Date(moment().format());
                    user.save(function(error, user) {
                        if(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }else {
                            console.log("User " + user.email + " received the confirmation e-mail successfully!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            console.log("No action was found for " + action);
            break;
    };
});

server.listen(80, function() {
    console.log("Listening!");
});
```

Here is my passport.js:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function(req, email, password, done){
        User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user) {
            if(err) return done(err);
            if(!user) return done(null, false, null);
            if(!user.comparePasswordHashes(data.pass, user.register.password)) return done(null, false, null);
            return done(null);
        })
    }));
}
```

And here is my index.js route where i'm getting the passport undefined:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    var indexController = app.controllers.index;
    app.get('/', indexController.index);
    app.post('/login', indexController.login);
    app.post('/register', indexController.register);

    app.post('/passport', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/logado',
        failureRedirect: '/falhou',
        failureFlash: false
    }));

};
```

Comment: Where is the require() for the last index.js route ?

Comment: on line load('models').then('controllers').then('routes').into(app, passport); I load all my routes. But the routes dont receive the passport.

Comment: are the routes being loaded when you don't include passport?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine without passport, but when i try to use it doesnt work. The error is: passport.authenthicate is not a function. On the route.